# Trabalhar com imagens no Android Studio

Tags: android, listview

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de trabalhar com imagens no android. Tenho uma List View, nessa lista tenho varias categorias. Quando o usuário selecionar esta categoria, gostaria que carregasse todas as imagens relacionas a esta categorias. Porem não sei como fazer isso, estou utilizando fragments. Tenho um arquivo xml com a list view e outro com o fragment onde apareceria as imagens.

Essa e a classe main:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
ListView listItemView;

String[] listaCategorias = new String[]{"INÍCIO", "RESPOSTAS","PERGUNTAS","ALFABETO","ALMOÇO","BEBIDAS", "COMO ESTOU ME SENTINDO",
        "EU QUERO","FAMILIA", "FRUTAS", "HIGIENE FEMININA", "HIGIENE MASCULINA","INFORMÁTICA", "LEGUMES", "MANICURE",
        "MAQUIAGEM","MUSICAS", "NUMERAIS","ONDE ESTÁ?", "SENTIMENTOS", "TAMANHOS", "VERDURAS"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Fragment1 fragment1 = (Fragment1) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
    listItemView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listaCategorias);
    listItemView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listItemView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, listaCategorias[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (position){
                case 1:


            }
        }
    });

}
```

E esta e a classe fragment, no qual as imagens apareceriam:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup conteiner, Bundle saveInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frag_1, conteiner, false);
    /*ImageView  imageView   = null;
    imageView.findViewById( R.id.imageView ) ;

    Glide . with ( this )
            . load ( "http://goo.gl/gEgYUd" )
            . into ( imageView ) ;*/
    return (view);

}
```

Comment: Você tem as URLs de todas as imagens que quer carregar?

Comment: Sim, todas estão na pasta drawable

Comment: R.id.imageView é uma variável do tipo int que aponta para a pasta drawable.
Mas....é muito mais simples carregar um array já definido e passar como parâmetro quando se clica na lista...(um array do tipo int preenchido com os caminhos). Ex: Clicou na posicao 5 da lista(categoria alimentos) > carrega um array > passa o aray por parametro > preenche lista.

Ex: int [] imagens= new int[10];
imagens[0] = R.id.img1; // e assim por diante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não sei se entendi sua pergunta. Mas já considerou criar um objeto que tem a referencia da imagem e a referencia da categoria? Com isso voce poderia ordenar ou filtrar de acordo com os objetos.

```
class Foo {
     private int imageRef;
     private int categoryRef;
     ...
}
```

Ai você poderia passar para o ListView o array de objetos, e também teria que criar um ArrayAdapter customizado. Espero que sua duvida tenha sido essa flws.